# How to remove empty element in global variables in xsl?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to remove empty elements in xml using xsl.After lots of attmpts, I found it appears differently when apply a template on origin-tree and global variable.Below is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:f="f:f"
                exclude-result-prefixes="f xs xsl">
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vPop" as="element()*">
    <!-- Variables to be generated -->
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="seq" select="f:subTree($vPop/@path/concat(.,'/',string(..)))"/>

    <xsl:variable name="a">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$seq" mode="format"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$a" mode="trim"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="trim">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
                          "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction())
     and normalize-space()=''
      ]"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data" mode="format">
        <Data>
           <!-- Some xsl:for-each and xsl:copy-of here -->
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Root">
            <Root>
                <xsl:for-each select="Info">
                    <Info>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="./*"></xsl:copy-of>
                    </Info>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$b"/>
            </IMFRoot>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:subTree" as="node()*">
        <xsl:param name="pPaths" as="xs:string*"/>

        <xsl:for-each-group select="$pPaths" group-adjacent=
                "substring-before(substring-after(concat(., '/'), '/'), '/')">
            <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key()">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=
                                      "substring-after(current-group()[1], current-grouping-key())">
                        <xsl:element name=
                                             "{substring-before(concat(current-grouping-key(), '['), '[')}">
                            <xsl:sequence select=
                                                  "f:subTree(for $s in current-group()
                         return
                            concat('/',substring-after(substring($s, 2),'/'))
                             )
            "/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First of all, I will set the variables that will be generated to **vPop**.
Secondly, format the generated xml with `match='Data'` template.
And then remove the empty element.
Finally, attach the result into the input tree.

Input Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Info>
        <Name>Stack</Name>
    </Info>
</Root>
```

Generated Xml after format ($a):

```
<Data>
    <Mode>Auto</Mode>
    <Componey></Componey>
    <Class>
        <Details>
            <Version>1.0.0</Version>
            <LastUpate/>
        </Details>
        <Package>com</Package>
        <Identity/>
    </Class>
</Data>
```

After remove the empty element ($b):

```
<Data>
    <Mode>Auto</Mode>
    <Class>
        <Details>
            <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        </Details>
        <Package>com</Package>
    </Class>
</Data>
```

Result tree:

```
<Root>
    <Info>
        <Name>Stack</Name>
    </Info>
    <Data>
        <Mode>Auto</Mode>
        <Class>
            <Details>
                <Version>1.0.0</Version>
            </Details>
            <Package>com</Package>
        </Class>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

But in my test run, the result tree appears to be like:

```
<Root>
    <Info>
        <Name>Stack</Name>
    </Info>
    <Data>Auto1.0.0com</Data>
</Root>
```

All the child nodes under Root are missing.

How could I put a template on a global variable correctly?

I'va tried to test the `match='node()'` template directly on the origin tree,it works fine.But after i put the template on global variables the output child nodes are missing.
I also tried to remove mode variable on

```
<xsl:variable name="b">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$a" mode="trim"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="trim">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

but the variable b seems to unable to find the right template.

**Update:**
After a template match, those nodes that unable to match the tempalte seem to be set null.So is it corret to copy the non-empty node rather than remove the empty node?

Comment: That is a lot of code but usually, if you have `<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="trim">`, inside, for any `apply-templates`, to use templates from that mode, you want/need `<xsl:apply-templates mode="#current" select=.../>` so I think you are missing to set the mode on the apply-templates.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I did set the mode variable `<xsl:apply-templates select="$a" mode="trim"/>`. I wonder that in a global variable situation, the node which does not match any template will be set to null? so in my code, those node match the template will be removed and those doesn't will be set to null?

Comment: If you want to use a mode, do that consistently; for that, your `apply-templates select="@*|node()"` needs `mode="#current"`. And the template for empty elements should perhaps have the mode set as trim.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Much appreciate！Sorry i didn't catch you at first time. Your solution works fine. But the match rule doesn't work, it can't remove the parent node if the child node of it been removed, i'll work it out.Still, Thank you again.